# How to Delete and Referesh Google Cached Pages

Tags: seo

I have made changes in my website title, meta keywords and many other changes on the pages but google is still showing old keywords. How can google reflect latest changes whenever i make? can any one help me to referesh google cache?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tell you this, but I think no one can help you refresh Google Cache. The only thing you can do is wait, until Google crawls your web site.

It seems you just start doing SEO now. So the first thing is be patient, there are lot of things you need to do afterward, especially you need to create good, relevant and fresh content, so as to improve the frequency of Google's crawl.

Besides, it is definitely helpful if you get lot of inbound links from relevant sites, improving the choice of presence to Google crawler.

Google Luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, I tried it and it was successful.

Please follow the steps from this link: http://labs.seoclick.com/request-outdated-cache-removal-google.html

I used this feature to crawl web page title from my site instead of from Google cache. Here is the snapshot.

[image]