# URL Rewrite Substring

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

How would I substring the request url in a rewrite config?

For example:
`www.domain.com/some-request)` `->` `www.domain.com/some-request`

Just removing one letter from the end of the url.

**Edit**:
I want to be able to do this from the url rewrite module config like so:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" /></conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
string url = "www.domain.com/some-request)";
string sub = url.Substring(0, url.Length - 1);
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kp5DOw)

Or if you know the last character will always be a `)`, just do:

```
"www.domain.com/some-request)".TrimEnd(')');
```

Comment: How would I do this using Asp Rewrite configuration, not from code

Comment: @ThomasOwers Can you provide some context to your problem please. Why do you need to do this in the config? Where are requests coming from that they are malformed like this? Surely the issue is in whatever is generating these requests/urls?

Comment: It's from an SEO issue where the canonical link on every page got malformed slightly and now we're getting crawlers adding a `)` onto the end of requests and therefore getting 404's. The original issue has been fixed, but a lot of crawlers have the malformed link cached

Comment: It doesn't sound like a problem for SO in that case. You need to somehow force the crawlers to refresh their cached links. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666558/how-to-delete-and-referesh-google-cached-pages) somewhere to start looking.